# Python: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer (Loop using defined function to created variables)

Tags: python

```
    def on_time_daysx(repayment_date, end_date, on_time_date, start_date):
        if repayment_date == end_date:

            on_time_days = (on_time_date - start_date).days + 1
        else:
            on_time_days = (on_time_date - start_date).days

        return on_time_days

for s in range(1,5):
    from datetime import date
    globals()[f"on_time_days{s}"] = on_time_daysx(repayment_date, end_date, on_time_date, date([f'start_date{s}']))
```

I have start_date1 to start_date5 as variables and want to use them in the function to create variables for on_time_days1 to on_time_days5.

New to python and generally coding.

Comment: Is this your whole code? Or are there other parts you've omitted here?

Comment: In general to avoid TypeErrors it's a good practice to use type hints, expecially for big files.

Comment: Yes, but this is the only bit that has an issue, all the parts in the function are defined variables

Comment: Don't do this: `globals()[f"on_time_days{s}"]`. It's  brittle and error prone and impossible to maintain. Create a dictionary called `on_time_days` and assign values to it using `on_time_days[s] = *expr*`.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the error happens in your last line. date is expecting an integer, but you are passing a list containing one string ([f'start_date{s}']).

I can recommend using strptime, which converts strings into datetime objects. You can read that up here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Another thing I see here is that you import a package inside a loop. That means it's imported over and over again. Usually, packages are imported at the very beginning of a file.

Best,
Joey